# How to download images from URL and cache the for Android (React-Native)

Tags: react-native

I need to download an image from the url and cache it to the cache directory of the application. I am developing the application on react-native platform. My teammate that works on IOS has a prop for  that allows to cache images as far I understand, and this prop is not supported yet on Android. I need a good way for caching images for Android.

The version of react-native: 0.60.5

I have tried using rn-fetch-blob library. I manged to store an image in the cache, but however, when I use the path

```
RNFetchBlob
  .config({
    fileCache : true,
    appendExt : 'jpg'
  })
  .fetch('GET', 'some url from firebase storage', {
  })
  .then((res) => {
     this.setState({ imagePAth: res.path() })
  })
```

```
<Image
  style={{ width: 200, height: 200, resizeMode: "contain" }}
  source={{ uri: "file://" + this.state.imagePath }}
/>
```

It does not render the image.

My other teammates said that react-native-fs library is broken and it does not work. So I trusted them, but if there is anybody who managed to do that with react-native-fs, please let me know.

I also tried using react-native-cached-image, but it was always giving me and error

```
undefined is not an object Netinfo.isconnected
```

The newest version of react-native-cached-image requires netinfo library by react-native-community. I was connected to the internet by the way. I was using the code example in the library to test it.

If you need to referecne the library I used: https://github.com/fungilation/react-native-cached-image

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `react-native-fast-image` it is really good for dealing with caching images. It makes managing the images and cache much easier than doing it yourself.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for the reply. I found this the library react-native-image-cache-hoc. It works fine for both IOS and Android.

Comment: I’ve released a new package about image caching on file system: https://github.com/georstat/react-native-image-cache it uses `react-native-file-access` under the hood witch is well mentained instead of `react-native-fetch-blob`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `react-native-fast-image`

```
yarn add react-native-fast-image or npm install --save react-native-fast-image
```

> **Note**: You must be using React Native 0.60.0 or higher to use the most
>   recent version of react-native-fast-image.

### Example

```js
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'

const YourImage = () => (
    <FastImage
        style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
        source={{
            uri: 'https://unsplash.it/400/400?image=1',
            headers: { Authorization: 'someAuthToken' },
            priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the replies. I found another library that works find on both IOS and Android. `react-native-image-cache-hoc`. At least it works fine on `react-native: 0.60.5`. I did not try `react-native-fast-image`, but if people say that it works, then it should be.

Please refer to: https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-image-cache-hoc
If you interested in the library.

Comment: I get [TypeError: Network request failed] when I tried to use react-native-image-cache-hoc. Have you faced this before?

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I has not been here for a while. After some time the package stopped working for me and I set up ```react-native-fast-image```